# Connect to MSSQL 2014 using Node.js

Tags: javascript, sql-server, npm

I've been looking at this for quite sometime and I'm truly stumped.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
const sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');
const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool({
  server: '127.0.0.1',
  database: 'Test',
  driver: 'msnodesqlv8',
  port: 1234,
  options: {
    trustedConnection: true
  }
})

pool.connect().then(() => {

  pool.request().query('select * from test1', (err, result) => {
        console.dir(result)
    })
})
```

Strange part is if I connect to "master" database and access a system table, it works fine, but once I switch it to a different database on the same server, an error occurs: "Login failed for user ..."

I have tried the following already:
1. Enable TCP/IP
2. Made sure SQL Server service, SQL browser service, and SQL service agent are running
3. I have granted full access to my windows user

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm using the npm mssql package, but if you can suggest another one that works, that would be great. I've tried my luck with seriate and I tried downloading node-sqlserver as well, but the latter seems to not be maintained anymore

Comment: Check the SQL Server error log. The login failed message there will include additional information as to the cause of the login failed.

Comment: Checked the logs; it says "failed to open explicitly specified database "Test". [CLIENT: <named pipe>].  I can access it via SSMS and I've made the user the owner of the database, but still there's a problem

Comment: That error indicates that either database `Test` does not exist on the server or the account you are using does not have permissions to use it. When you say you granted full access to your windows user, did that include SQL Server permissions?

Comment: Yes, I have. I right-hand clicked on the database itself, and made sure under "permissions", my user was included in the list "user roles" and then I checked all permissions: alter, etc. After that I right-hand clicked on the table itself, went to permissions, and checked all: alter, control, etc. Since my app can access master database, I even tried copying the same permissions as master, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @DanGuzman: could it be that my app is looking at something like a LocalDB that has its own master, etc, and no Test database, and I'm looking at another set of databases? When I connect via SSMS, I use (localdb)/v11.0 as the server name and in my app, I use "server: 127.0.0.1". Are these the same?

Comment: Just answered  my own question! I was looking at 2 different "localhost". The one in SSMS was the default one (localdb)/v11.0 while the one my app was looking at was "localhost.\ (instance name)".

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did to make sure that my app connects to MSSQL:

1. Make sure SQL server service is running
2. Make sure the SQL server browser service is running
3. Make sure you've given the user, that is being used to connect to the database from your app, SQL priviledges
4. Make sure TCP/IP is enabled and you're connecting on the correct port.

AND FINALLY...

5. Make sure your app and the database you're creating are actually the same "localhost". (I was connected to LocalDB and my app was connected to localhost.(named instance))

You can checking if the services are running by looking at SQL Server Configuration Manager

Hope this helps anyone who is facing the same issue